# Meaning of linearization of an action

Tags: algebraic-groups

What means the following expression:

> Every action of an affine algebraic group on an affine algebraic variety can be linearized.

Comment: Where is that sentence from?

Comment: I have a problem which say: "Accepting that every action of an affine algebraic group on an affine algebraic variety can be linearized prove that every affine algebraic group is isomorphic ta a closed subgroup of $GL_n$, for some $n$."

Comment: That does not actually say where it is from.

Comment: It's only an exercise that I have to do, I don't know where it's from.

Comment: Then it might be better to ask whoever gave you the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement should mean the following:

There exists a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ on which the affine algebraic group $G$ acts in such a way that the affine algebraic variety $X$ is a subvariety of $V$ and the action of $G$ on $V$ restricts to the given action of $G$ on $X$.